# ‘Incorrect checksum for freed object’ error after upgrading project to Xcode 4.2 and iOS 5

Tags: malloc, ios5, nsdateformatter

When I recently upgraded my iPhone to iOS 5 and upgraded Xcode, the  project I've worked on for 5 months now has one error after another.  Prior to this, I had successfully run Analyze and Profile without any issues.  Now, I get one error corrected and another pops up.

I good example is the following code:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm"];
NSString *dateStr = [formatter stringFromDate:self.chargeDate];
[formatter release];
```

I've used this hundreds of times without any problem.  Now, I get the following error about every 3rd time I run the code:

```
incorrect checksum for freed object
```

What could be causing this error?

Comment: Meant to include the error occurs on the first line.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing particularly wrong with the code you posted. The fact that you are getting errors on the first allocation line shows that you have got heap corruption due to bad memory management elsewhere in your app. This will be tough to diagnose. Sorry.

You've managed to 'get away' with it up till now but the underlying problem has probably always been there. It's just that moving to iOS5 has made it apparent.